# How to read in order to improve my writing skills?

Tags: style, reading

It's fairly common wisdom to say that one must read to improve their writing style.

I am looking for techniques or activities to do while reading books. I mean, should I analyze the sentences' structures, the rhyme, etc., and most importantly how to it?

I am looking for resources that show how to do this. Typically, I am looking for a resource (book/podcast/blog posts/whatever) that takes examples of good stuff and explains, **in detail**, **why** it's actually good. Other suggestions are welcome as well.

PS: I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: You ask "how." But it seems like maybe you want to know "what" to read. There are some guides to how to write various types of thing. Mostly they satisfy Sturgeon's Law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law So, be aware of the potentially low quality of any such guide.  But it is very hard to develop writing theory on your own.

Answer (score 5):

### The reason why reading can improve your writing is that writing can't be taught but can be learned.

While there are specific crafts of writing that can be taught: grammar, sentence structure, and point of view, the heart of writing is about getting your story and ideas into someone else's brain, creating an immersive and engaging experience.

A few things I've learned to do, and things my instructors have encouraged, are:

- Read the same piece over and over.
- Read good writing and intentionally read bad writing. Compare them and try and work out why some are good and some suck.
- Assess the ratio of prose given to setting, narrative, dialogue, and interiority -- using different color highlighters.
- Notice and mark which sentences in a piece you like the most when you read it. Take them apart as a writer and work to understand what you are responding to when you read them.
- Take note what you learn in a story and when it becomes important. How is the flow of information part of your enjoyment experience?

There are a lot more, too many to list. But, it all kind of boils down to is understanding how an author created the piece you are reading so you would enjoy reading it.  The converse is also important: what did they do that you found boring or ineffective? The idea is to keep in your mind 'Why did the author make this choice when writing this sentence' for every sentence in a piece.

Comment: "Assess the ratio of prose given to setting, narrative, dialogue, and interiority -- using different color highlighters." Do you know about [Margie Lawson's EDITS method](https://www.margielawson.com/product/digging-deep-into-the-edits-system/)? If not, it uses this technique as well, you should check it out!

Comment: This looks like pretty good advice. Thank you.

Comment: You can learn writing from any creative work, not just the written word. Personally, I like to read through the work's page on [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org) (just search for the title in the bar at the top right) and think about how the writer(s) employed the listed tropes, what they accomplished with those tropes, whether I liked or disliked the resulting story structure, etc. But only after I finish it, of course!

Comment: writing can't be taught **[citation needed]** - I can google the commonplace belief and the quote so don't bother. But I don't share that belief. You can surely teach a person to imprint squiggly glyphs on paper following some predetermined sequences. That's writing words. You can teach structure, tempo, expressions, timing, idioms, and mashing it all together. That's also writing. Your bar for what "writing" stands for is rather high. Splash paint on canvas and you are painting. You are just not doing good painting.

Answer (score 3):

While reading the book the first time, I believe the first priority is to just read the book and enjoy it (or hate it) or at least try to, and *only after that* go back and analyze the text. This is how the majority of your readers will read your texts (except for the analysis), and it will make it easier for you to learn how to make your readers enjoy your texts.

Of course, if you get an idea while reading the book, that's what the margin/post-it notes are for (or for that matter, the note function in your e-book reader). Make notes as you need them, but initially focus on consuming the book as a reader.

Once you've read the book you can start analyzing it. Here I suggest you read a writing book or two, pick an aspect of storytelling, for instance, structure, and analyze how authors do that in their works. Then move on to the next aspect, for instance, scene endings or character arcs, or dialog. And so on. You should probably read more fiction and books on writing as well while doing this.

Some people will sometimes get stuck analyzing an aspect or several for years and while reading will make notes on good or bad examples they come across... I guess, in some cases, this could even hamper the pure enjoyment of reading, and while a lost opportunity, it's sometimes needed in order to get to the next level.

Your next priority, if your goal is to write, is to write every day while you read and analyze books. Maybe you'll just write a sentence or two, but still, don't forget that it only happens on the page, and only if you put words on that page.

A fun combination of writing and reading is to write what you read. This means picking a book and typing a page or two of it, verbatim, in order to "follow in the author's footsteps" and "feel" their writing letter by letter.

A lot of writing books and other resources will also use works of fiction as part of the explanation or as examples for the techniques being discussed. This can be a good way to get your own analysis going.

A good free resource is K.M. Weiland's [helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com](https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/). She uses a lot of books and movies as examples in her articles and even has a database of films/books where the different plot points have been analyzed.

Another approach, one I've used, but which takes tons of time, is to just enjoy reading or watching TV or movies and do enormous amounts of them until you've simmered enough in it that you start recognizing the format of stories, the boring repetitions you want to avoid and so on. I combined this with reading books, blogs, etc on writing, storytelling, characters, and even screenwriting. This way could give you a more organic feeling for stories, but it will take longer. And you still need to "study" to learn to write, but this will help you get a feel for what to write, or what not to write, once you've figured out how to write.

A third approach, the "feet first approach" is to start writing a text and when you get stuck, for instance, writing dialog, bring out the writing books and the examples of fiction to figure out how to do it.